# Change default name PG Build App in PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I would like to know how I can change the default name for my app in **phonegap** build, when uploading zipped files, PhoneGap Build gives **PG Build App** as its default name, how can I change it?

[image: Click here to see the screenshoot]

PhoneGap interface provides input to suggest the app name but no button to submit the change.

Answer (score 3):

Have you noticed the tip at the right side of your screenshot? You need to include a config.xml in the root www folder of your zip file which allows you to specify the name, version, icon, splash screen, plugins, and many other settings for your app.

Here is a sample config.xml. Notice the app name on the third line:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.mobile" version="2.25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name>My Amazing App</name>
  <description>This is the best app ever.</description>
  <author email="info@myapp.com" href="http://www.myapp.com">Amazing App Team</author>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.3.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="3.2.2" />

  <icon src="icon.png" />
  <splash src="splash.png" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, actually it was a case of not placing config.xml www folder.

Comment: @Racil, Your answer give me attention to check exact folder path for config.xml file. By default the config.xml file is in main project folder so we have to move to www folder. Thanks a lot buddy.